# Unexpected kernel model trap error using windows 8.1 family safety and avast

Tags: windows-8, bsod, user-accounts, parental-controls, avast

*Does anyone know of a way that I can use the family safety feature in Windows 8.1 (64 bit) and keep Avast Internet Security 2016*?

I am using Windows 8.1 which allows for applying family safety to user accounts.  This adds web filters and can also restrict apps and limit times.  When we attempt to log into a user account that has family safety applied, the screen turns blue and says that my PC ran into a problem and needs to restart.  I also says to search online for this error: unexpected_kernel_mode_trap.  Then it shuts down and restarts.

After researching support solutions, I have found that lots of people have this problem and the only solution offered by Microsoft is to uninstall Avast.  From Avast online support the problem seems to be Windows 8 and 8.1.  Microsoft and Avast support communities blame each other.

I uninstalled Avast using their uninstall utility and reinstalled the lasted version again, but still the same problem.

When I uninstall Avast, I can login to a child account with no problems, but when I reinstall Avast the problem returns. Even when I set the child account to allow all apps, the computer crashes when I try to log in to the child account. Sometimes I get as far as the user start page showing that family safety is engaged, then it crashes.

My system and Avast and everything I can find is all updated as far as I can find.

Other troubleshooting I've tried:
One by one I disabled the active shields in Avast to see which, if any, might be the culprit.  But whether all are disabled or just one at a time, the problem persists.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the child account connected to a Microsoft Account?

Comment: @TeaJay Have you added Avast to the list of applications allowed by this user?

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question to reflect the answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound I've added even more information and some more troubleshooting that I've tried.  Do you have any more suggestions?  Thanks for your help!